# Liferay 7.1 : Cluster with only one node (test environnement)

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to know if it is possible to have only one node in a cluster environement for our Liferay 7.1 in localhost.

Here is a part of my portal-ext :

```
cluster.link.enabled=true
cluster.link.channel.properties.control=/custom_jgroups/tcp.xml
cluster.link.channel.properties.transport.0=/custom_jgroups/tcp.xml
```

I set following properties on VM Options for my tomcat :

```
-Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1  
-Djgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts=127.0.0.1[7800]
```

In a portlet I do to execute manually a job :

```
Message message = new Message();
message.put(SchedulerEngine.JOB_NAME, job);
message.put(SchedulerEngine.GROUP_NAME , job);
message.put(SchedulerEngine.DESTINATION_NAME, DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH);
message.setDestinationName(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH);
log.info("Stream " + streamNumber + " is launched ("+job+")");
try {
    ClusterLinkUtil.sendMulticastMessage(message, Priority.LEVEL10);
} catch (Exception e){
    log.error(e);
}
```

In production with two nodes in my cluster it works but in test with one node, nothing happens.

Here is the log debug. It appears that message is sent but not received ... Any ideas ?

```
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6][ClusterLinkImpl:131] Select channel number 0 for priority LEVEL10
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-6][JGroupsClusterChannel:171] Send multicast message {destinationName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=null, values={GROUP_NAME=com.job.UselessDataPurgeJob, DESTINATION_NAME=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, JOB_NAME=com.job.UselessDataPurgeJob}}
```

Comment: For debugging, you could try to increase your log level to DEBUG in serveradministration for: `com.liferay.portal.cluster.multiple.internal.ClusterLinkImpl` and `com.liferay.portal.cluster.multiple.internal.jgroups.JGroupsClusterChannel` - there is some debug logging for send/receive of messages

Comment: Thanks. Post edited.

Comment: I am not sure if multicast messages should be received by the sender. Multicast usually says: sender communicates to a group of receivers. Do you receive a message on the sender node of your 2-node Prod evironment?

Comment: Yes I think so, because my job is a MEMORY CLUSTERED job. Liferay triggers it only on one node and always the same (master). So if i call this on the master, it sends the multicast message and launch the job on himself.